# Chained Method Calls in Python with dict

Tags: python

I needed to flatten a dictionary today.  Meaning I wanted:

```
{'_id': 0, 'sub': {'a': 1, 'b':2}}
```

to become:

```
{'_id': 0, 'a':1, 'b':2}
```

So I thought I could be clever and pull off the following one-liner.

### One-liner:

```
x = dict(_id=0, sub=dict(a=1, b=2))
y = x.pop('sub').update(x)  # incorrect result
```

This results in `y = None`.

So I obviously resorted to:

### Multi-Step:

```
x = dict(_id=0, sub=dict(a=1, b=2))
y = x.pop('sub')
y.update(x)   # correct result
```

Setting "good expressive coding practices" asside for a moment, I would like to understand why the **One-liner** approach above yields `None`.  I would have thought that x.pop('sub') would have resulted in a temporary dict on a stack somewhere and the original x dict would be immediately updated.  Then the stack object would receive the next method in the chain which is the update.  This obviously does not seem to be the case.

For the communities better understanding (and clearly mine) - how does python resolve the one-liner and result in **None**?

Comment: Thanks Martijn and sr2222.  Very obvious after I get past the very bad habit of forgetting that update ONLY works in place.  For some reason I feel like it should also return the ref to the object for chaining purposes. Likely there was a dict somewhere in memory that would have held the correct result but obviously not accessible by any reference once the line completed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.update()` method returns `None`, because it alters the affected dictionary in-place. `.pop()` does return the popped value, the nested dictionary.

You are updating the contained `dict`, why not update the *parent* `dict` instead?

```
x.update(x.pop('sub'))
```

Result:

```
>>> x = dict(_id=0, sub=dict(a=1, b=2))
>>> x.update(x.pop('sub'))
>>> x
{'a': 1, '_id': 0, 'b': 2}
```

Or you could do this recursively:

```
def inplace_flatten(d):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    for k in keys:
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            inplace_flatten(d[k])
            d.update(d.pop(k))
```

Comment: ... and yes. Inverting the steps as you suggest is a very slick way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Because `y` gets the result of `dict.update()`, which is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
def flatten(d, answer=None):
    if answer == None:
        answer = {}
    if not d:
        return answer
    else:
        for k in d:
            if isinstance(d[k], dict):
                flatten(d[k], answer)
            else:
                answer[k] = d[k]
        return answer
```